# Can't run Maven commands because no pom.xml in directory, but pom.xml doesn't show up in search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, maven, maven-3, sutime

When I run mvn commands, I'm getting this error back:

```
Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory
(/Users/hojung). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
```

However, I'm not finding POM in *any* directory at all. Has anyone run into/solved a variation of this same problem?

This is the command I'm running btw, in order to set up the installation for [sutime](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime):

`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./jars`

Comment: Maven is a build tool. To be used as a build tool it needs something to build. A pom.xml defines what maven is meant to build. Any project intended to be built with maven will define a pom somewhere, which maven can then use.

Comment: https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime seems to have a pom.xml defined in it's top level directory

Comment: Make sure that you invoke maven from the directory which contains the pom in question.

Comment: Ah, I see - which directory should I be invoking maven from?

Comment: Ah, also, it seems that `pip install sutime` actually installs a directory that doesn't include a pom.xml file. Strange, because the Github does have a pom.xml in its main directory

Comment: Got it by just downloading the pom.xml file independently from sutime library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There is no Maven without a `pom.xml` file

Maven uses a pom.xml file as sort of a configuration file. It has information about how to compile, what to compile, when to compile, libraries to import, etc. If you don't have a pom.xml, there is nothing for Maven to do.

So there is nothing to "solve".

If your repository does not have a pom.xml file, then it can't run Maven commands. Which means you need to re-download (re-pull) the file from the repository. My guess is it got moved/deleted by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did a project last week with SUTime, you must download [SUTime](https://github.com/FraBle/python-sutime) repository, in the repositoyr you see a `pom.xml` file, after that run your code

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=./jars
```

in that directory.